# Visual Studio saving

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

So, I want to upgrade to Visual Studio 2012 but im working on a project with somebody else who has Visual Studio 2010. Will I be able to open and save to the same project without breaking the file for the other guy (with the old verison of Visual Studio)?

I'm asking this because i know that a project made in visual studio 2010 can't be opened with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has published [a compatibility chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#sectionToggle0) of things that are compatible between VS2010 and VS2012.

The kind of sharing you are describing is called "[Round Tripping](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/28/round-tripping-with-visual-studio-11.aspx)" the project. 
If it is a basic C# or VB.NET project running on .NET 4.0 or older you are fine to share. If it is something more than that please check the compatibility chart.